# Nimbus Look&Feel refresh Painter

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, nimbus

I'm using the Nimbus look & feel in my swing application.

I set the primary and secondary properties of the `UIDefaults` of the look & feel.
The colors are right. Now i have the problem, that the painter of the components use the colors, which were defined before updating the color theme.

Is there a way, to update the painters of all components to use the new colors, or do I need to implement a custom painter for each property?

I already call `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(window)` after setting the properties in the `UIDefaults`.

EDIT:

The following code sets the L&F of the whole application:

```
try {
    for( LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels() ) {
        if( "Nimbus".equals( info.getName() ) ) {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
            customizeNimbusLaF();
            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI( appWindow );
            break;
        }
    }
}
catch( Exception e ) {
    LogUtility.warning( "cannot set application look and feel" );
    LogUtility.warning( e.getMessage() );
}
```

The code does, what it is supposed to do (setting the Nimbus Look & Feel).
The problem is, that the `Painters` of the Menu and other components work with the old colors.

The following code sets the colors:

```
private final void customizeNimbusLaF() {       
    UIManager.put( "control" , UIConstants.GREY_LIGHT );
    UIManager.put( "nimbusAlertYellow" , UIConstants.YELLOW );
    UIManager.put( "nimbusBase" , UIConstants.GREY_DARK );
    UIManager.put( "nimbusDisabledText" , UIConstants.GREY_DARK );
    UIManager.put( "nimbusFocus" , UIConstants.BLUE_LIGHT );
    UIManager.put( "nimbusGreen" , UIConstants.GREEN );
    UIManager.put( "nimbusInfoBlue" , UIConstants.BLUE_MIDDLE );
    UIManager.put( "nimbusRed", UIConstants.RED );
    UIManager.put( "nimbusSelectionBackground",
    UIConstants.BLUE_MIDDLE );

    UIManager.put( "background" ,UIConstants.GREY_LIGHT );
    UIManager.put( "controlDkShadow" , UIConstants.GREY_DARK );
    UIManager.put( "controlShadow", UIConstants.GREY_MIDDLE );
    UIManager.put( "desktop", UIConstants.BLUE_MIDDLE );
    UIManager.put( "menu", UIConstants.GREY_LIGHT );
    UIManager.put( "nimbusBorder", UIConstants.GREY_MIDDLE );
    UIManager.put( "nimbusSelection", UIConstants.BLUE_MIDDLE );
    UIManager.put( "textBackground", UIConstants.BLUE_LIGHT );
    UIManager.put( "textHighlight", UIConstants.BLUE_LIGHT );
    UIManager.put( "textInactiveText", UIConstants.GREY_MIDDLE );

    // panel
    UIManager.put( "Panel.background", UIConstants.GREY_LIGHT );
    UIManager.put( "Panel.disabled", UIConstants.GREY_LIGHT );
    UIManager.put( "Panel.font", UIConstants.DEFAULT_FONT );
    UIManager.put( "Panel.opaque", true );

    // button
    UIManager.put( "Button.background", UIConstants.GREY_LIGHT );
    UIManager.put( "Button.disabled", UIConstants.GREY_LIGHT );
    UIManager.put( "Button.disabledText", UIConstants.BLUE_MIDDLE );
    UIManager.put( "Button.font", UIConstants.DEFAULT_FONT );

    // menu
    UIManager.put( "Menu.background", UIConstants.GREY_LIGHT );
    UIManager.put( "Menu.disabled", UIConstants.GREY_LIGHT );
    UIManager.put( "Menu.disabledText", UIConstants.GREY_DARK );
    UIManager.put( "Menu.font", UIConstants.MENU_FONT );
    UIManager.put( "Menu.foreground", UIConstants.BLACK );
    UIManager.put( "Menu[Disabled].textForeground",
            UIConstants.GREY_MIDDLE );
    UIManager.put( "Menu[Enabled].textForeground", UIConstants.BLACK );
    UIManager.put( "MenuBar.background", UIConstants.GREY_LIGHT );
    UIManager.put( "MenuBar.disabled", UIConstants.GREY_LIGHT );
    UIManager.put( "MenuBar.font", UIConstants.MENU_FONT );
    UIManager.put( "MenuBar:Menu[Disabled].textForeground",
            UIConstants.GREY_MIDDLE );
    UIManager.put( "MenuBar:Menu[Enabled].textForeground",
            UIConstants.BLACK );
    UIManager.put( "MenuItem.background", UIConstants.GREY_LIGHT );
    UIManager.put( "MenuItem.disabled", UIConstants.GREY_LIGHT );
    UIManager.put( "MenuItem.disabledText", UIConstants.GREY_MIDDLE );
    UIManager.put( "MenuItem.font", UIConstants.MENU_FONT );
    UIManager.put( "MenuItem.foreground", UIConstants.BLACK );
    UIManager.put( "MenuItem[Disabled].textForeground",
            UIConstants.GREY_MIDDLE );
    UIManager.put( "MenuItem[Enabled].textForeground",
            UIConstants.BLACK );

    // tree
    UIManager.put( "Tree.background", UIConstants.BLACK );      
}
```

The datatypes of the constants in `UIConstants` are either of type `Color` of `Font` depending of the attribute to be set.

Can someone tell me where my problem is?

Greets
Michael

Comment: `1.` which part of `SSCCE` you don't understand ???, erghttt !!!, `2.` then better could be to use `SeaGlass` or another `L&F` based on Nimbus, `3.` you reseted `Painter` in all cases where you used `background` for value painted by `Painter`, have to decide background or Painter

Comment: and why did you ignored code depots by @aephyr, all good that we  knows about Nimbus and its themes is there ....

Answer (score 4):

no idea what did you tried, because

- set all setting for `UImanager` before creating an `Swing GUI` and starting `AWT Thread`
- you have to call `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(window)` in all cases that `Swing GUI` is visible and you needed to change L&F on runtime
- separated issue could be with `XxxUIResources`, but no idea without seeing your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)
- for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrated your issue about `Nimbus L&F`, value for `UIManager` and `Colors` stays unchanged

Answer (score 0):

Change place on these to lines of code

```
       UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
       customizeNimbusLaF();
```

to

```
       customizeNimbusLaF();
       UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add an alternative to this method proposed here.

In particular, all the problems related to the UIManager described in the [following issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12387992/10854225) are solved by the [material-ui-swing](https://github.com/vincenzopalazzo/material-ui-swing) library with the concept of Material Theming System.

Material Theme System gives the possibility to set up your colors and style decision like with/without border, the border with round corner or not in a single class that is documented [here](https://vincenzopalazzo.github.io/material-ui-swing/) under the package `mdlaf.themes`.

An example of usage can be the following one

```
  try {
      JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
      JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(false);
      MaterialTheme theme = new MaterialLiteTheme();
      // here your custom config theme.setXXX();
      MaterialLookAndFeel material = new MaterialLookAndFeel(theme);
      UIManager.setLookAndFeel(material);
  } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

You can keep around also the Theme, makes your custom change and when you are read call `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(window)`